# StoreMI - Create Bootable StoreMI greyed out

Tags: windows, storage, amd-processor

Situation:  New PC Build 
- Windows 10 
- Samsung Evo 970 256GB NVME 
- WD Blue 1TB potato drive
- AMD Ryzen 7 2700X on Asus Crosshair VII Hero
- GTX 1070

One of the main benefits of Ryzen 2, for me, was the StoreMI feature that I really hope to get working.  I watched AdoredTV's video of how he set his up, but unfortunately for me, I'm not having any luck.

[Greyed Out no option to create Bootable StoreMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfjEN.png)

I have gone into Windows Disk Management and made sure the drives are visible to the OS, and they are also visible in File Explorer.

[Windows Sees the Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYrtn.png)

If I try to [remove fast media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22eld.png), [I get this message, and the program closes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdZRL.png)

If I try to modify, [I get nothing useful.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebv0l.png)

So...I need some help figuring out what I've done wrong.  Could I have something in the BIOS I need to fix?  Other?  I'm at a total loss.

Edit 1) I may have another clue?  One of my greyed out drives is the same drive as the drive that's selectable, and they're "both" in a Tier.  Looking at the Disk Manager, it seems my "System Reserved" is for some reason on the NVMe drive when it should have...I would have thought...been installed on the same drive the OS was installed on.  I know I didn't tell Windows to do this.

So maybe this is a clue?  Can I move the "System Reserved" Partition over to the spinning rust?  Would that help?

[Same Drive occupies both tiers?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sX8B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well AMD customer support never emailed me back.  It's been about 48 hours now.  Not counting the RTFM email which was useless.

So...I figured...Maybe I'll ask the people I learned the most about this from, either AdoredTV, or Level1Techs.  So I went to the Level1Techs forum, and talked to Wendell himself.  He diagnosed and suggested a fix (that worked) in about 5 minutes.  On my Windows install, I selected the C: (slow) drive to install the OS on, however, the OS set up the "System Reserved" partition on the NVMe drive...even though I never said to do that...it never asked if that's what I wanted to do...It just did it.  Effectively nullifying the ability of StoreMI to work.

Why AMD can't do what a youtuber can in 5 minutes is beyond me...and pretty inexcusable.  But I digress...

What I had to do was start over.  Backed everything up, inserted my Windows 10 installation USB, booted from that, and ****-F10 into a command line from there.

From there, I cleaned all my drives.

Next, I physically removed my NVMe from the motherboard, then went about reinstalling the OS on the slow drive...now the only drive in the system, so it was forced to partition that.

Once that was done, and the OS was completely installed, I shut down the system and reinstalled the NVMe.

Rebooted the system, and I was then able to configure StoreMI easily.

TLDR:  If you are doing a new system build, with a fresh Windows install, and want to use StoreMI... My recommendation is to install ONLY one HDD into your system (AMD recommends the install take place on the slowest drive).  Complete your Windows install, then install the remaining drive or drives (you can only use two drives with StoreMI), install StoreMI and configure.